# How to create a SOC constraints with different Variable vectors's element

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am working on an optimization problem with cvxpy. And I need to create a SOC(second order cone) constraint.
The way described in cvxpy documents is like following:

> We use cp.SOC(t, x) to create the SOC constraint ||x||_2 <= t.
>   where t is the scalar part of the second-order constraint, x is a matrix whose rows/columns are each a cone.

Here is the standard way how cvxpy solve a [SOCP problem](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/socp.html).

But now i need to extract `Variable` from different places.

```py
import cvxpy as cvx

Y = cvx.Variable(3)
Z = cvx.Variable(3)
T = cvx.Variable(3)
soc_constraints = []
for in range(3):
   t = T[i]
   x = np.matrix([Y[i], Z[i]])
   soc_constraints += [cvx.SOC(t, x)]
```

But I get one error here.

```py
AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'variables'
```

I suppose `x` should be a cvxpy expression. But how can i create a SOC constraint out of different Variable vectors.
Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are misusing `np.matrix()` for concatenation / matrix-building. Just use any of cvxpy's functions to do that (like `hstack`). Additionally, `np.matrix` is always calling for trouble in modern code as numpy's matrices are not numpy arrays and the former is mostly deprecated in most codes.

Comment: You are right. I am new to cvxpy and i think `hstack` is what i need. Thanks a lot.